# PHP encode and decode text to ASCII characters

Tags: php

I plan to make a class that can encode files into ASCII characters and decode into readable texts. Basically, the idea of my encoding is to encode all non-space characters into ASCII and replace the spaces into random non-numeric characters.

```
Example: "Hello World!" to "72101108108111^8711111410810033"
```

In this manner, if I have an entire file with multiple paragraphs and encode it, it wouldn't be so obvious that I converted the characters to ASCII. So far this is my code:

```
$text = str_split("Hello World!");
$content = "";
$random = str_split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*-+?/_=");
foreach($text as $t){
    if ($t == " "){
        $count = rand(1,66);
        $content .= $random[$count-1];
    }
    else
        $content .= ord($t);
}
echo $content."<br>";
$decode = str_split($content);
$script = "";
$tostring = "";
foreach($decode as $d){
    if (is_numeric($d)){
        $tostring .= $d;
    }else{
        $script .= chr($tostring);
        $tostring = "";
    }
}

echo $script;
```

I'm struggling to figure out the problem with my code. This is the result of it:

```
ASCII: 72101108108111-8711111410810033
TEXT: O
```

Please enlighten me!

Comment: `chr()` "Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by interpreting bytevalue as an unsigned integer." https://www.php.net/chr

Comment: `$random` contains alpha characters. If you want only non alpha characters shouldnt it be just `!@#$%^&*-+?/_=`? You also could just shuffle that array and use its first index... although going back is going to be hard wont it? You cant tell ones from tens and hundreds.

Comment: @miken32 now I see why. I've been converting an entire word instead of a single text. I'll try to reedit my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: you were attempting to pass multiple numbers to `chr()` which is designed to return a single character, and you had no way to tell how long your numbers were going to be. Using your example above: is it 72, 101, 108, 108 or is it 72, 10, 10, 81, 08? So, fix your numbers at 3 digits using `sprintf()` and then you'll know when to pass data to `chr()` and continue with your decoding.

```
$text = str_split("Hello World!");
$content = "";
$random = str_split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*-+?/_=");
foreach($text as $t){
    if ($t === " "){
        $count = rand(1, 66);
        $content .= $random[$count - 1];
    } else {
        // this will always be three digits now
        $content .= sprintf("%03d", ord($t));
    }
}
echo $content."<br>";
$decode = str_split($content);
$script = "";
$tostring = "";
foreach($decode as $d){
    if (is_numeric($d)){
        $tostring .= $d;
        if (strlen($tostring) === 3) {
            // you've got 3 numbers so you can decode and reset
            $script .= chr($tostring);
            $tostring = "";
        }
    } else {
        // also you weren't putting your spaces back in
        $script .= " ";
    }
}

echo $script;
```